# GitLab + GitLab CI + Dependent SSH projects via NPM

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Currently we're using GitLab to manage our repos and GitLab CI as our CI.

I have a project which includes another GitLab project as a dependency (via NPM). The project is internal and the URL in package.json starts with `git+ssh://git@`, which is what we use on our local machines. We have SSH keys set up.

However, GitLab CI doesn't seem to be able to use this same mechanism to install this dependent project (via `npm install`).

The error I get is:

```
npm install
npm ERR! git clone git@my.domain.com:developers/my-repo.git Cloning into bare repository '/home/gitlab_ci_runner/.npm/_git-remotes/git-my-domain-com-developers-my-git-26043eba'...
npm ERR! git clone git@my.domain.com:developers/my-repo.git
npm ERR! git clone git@my.domain.com:developers/my-repo.git Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! git clone git@my.domain.com:developers/my-repo.git fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
npm ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR!     at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-68-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/gitlab_ci_runner/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-9
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab_ci_runner/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-9/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What are we missing? I need a solution that doesn't require me to change the URL in the `package.json`.

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784182/how-to-pull-npm-dependency-from-private-gitlab-git-repo-during-gitlab-ci-build)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the correct host (`my.domain.com`) key in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on the CI server.

Usually just removing the line with the key from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, and then `ssh`ing into it at least once to cache the key.