# How to pull NPM dependency from private GitLab Git repo during GitLab CI build

Tags: git, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a job in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which does an `npm install` like so:

```
test:
  image: node:10
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm test
```

The problem is that I'm referencing a private GitLab repo in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "internal-dep": "git+https://gitlab.com/Company/internal-dep.git",
  ...
```

The `npm install` command works locally, since I'm already authed against GitLab, but fails on GitLab CI. How do I get `internal-dep` to resolve successfully on GitLab CI?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two approaches I've found that allow Git to auth successfully against GitLab during the `npm install` step (which uses Git under the hood to access this dependency).

First approach, as shown in this `.gitlab-ci.yml` job:

```
test:
  image: node:10
  script:
    - echo -e "machine gitlab.com\nlogin gitlab-ci-token\npassword ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
    - npm install
    - npm test
```

Second approach, which also seems to work:

```
test:
  image: node:10
  script:
    - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/".insteadOf https://gitlab.com/
    - npm install
    - npm test
```

Comment: I had a similar issue when moving from `npm install` to `npm ci` in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` (npm version 6).

In my case, the problem was some `git+ssh` references in `package-lock.json` (which `npm ci` is using) that was not present in `package.json` (which `npm install` is using).

Fixed it by altering npm to use `git+https` instead of `git+ssh` with this command before `npm ci`:

`git config --global url."https://gitlab.com".insteadOf ssh://git@gitlab.com`

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068174/running-npm-install-how-to-configure-not-to-use-ssh-port-blocked-by-firewall

Comment: Similar issue when trying to install a dependency using Python Poetry. I ran this command and it started working (making sure to specify the correct access token): `RUN git config --global url."https://access-token:ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE@maven.rangeforce.com/".insteadOf git@maven.rangeforce.com:`