# Running npm install - how to configure not to use SSH (port blocked by firewall)

Tags: git, npm-install

When I run `npm install` the majority of modules are configured properly. However, at least one wants to hit an `ssh://` address to pull the module. Unfortunately, my company has a policy not to allow SSH connections outside of the internal network.

The specific error I'm getting is:

```
Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/pemrouz/buble.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I don't have buble defined in my package.json so it's obviously a library something else depends on.

Is there a way to configure NPM to NOT use ssh:// addresses? I assume I should be able to download the module(s) from an HTTP address like all of the others -- can I tell it to convert from SSH to HTTP always?

I've tried a few things I found online:

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf ssh://` and `npm config set ssl-strict=false`

These did not solve this particular problem.

Comment: this [gist](https://gist.github.com/coin8086/7228b177221f6db913933021ac33bb92#use-proxy-for-gitgithub) might be of help. I suspect you need to set up git itself rather than npm

Comment: I have this problem with the NPM library: fullcalendar

Comment: You should probably consider manually downloading the failed package and install it.

Comment: @eftshift0 I need this for a CI/CD pipeline based on Jenkins

Answer (score 8):

> I've tried a few things I found online:

> ```
> git config --global url."https://".insteadOf ssh://
> ```

The actual command would be:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com
```

Otherwise Git would try an URL like `https://git@github.com`, which might not be well supported.

It `npm` still mentions SSH, then check the user running the `npm` command: it needs to the same as the one you did the global config.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know how do I configure the git integrated in Jenkins? I only found two fields to configure the user name and email...

Comment: @GuerricP As long as Jenkins is running with the same user account as the one you would use to type the `git config` command, that is enough. On Windows, make sure Jenkins is not running (as a service) using the System account.

Comment: how does this work when the uri is merely `git@github.com:user/project.git`?

Comment: @Otheus `insteadOf git@github:` should work just fine.

Comment: is there a way to configure it JUST for NPM, not for the usual SSH command? Problem is: while I am having repos on GitHub and prefer to use ssh for them, our CI server does not have an ssh key for GitHub and thus the `nom install` fails because the link in the `package-lock.json` is the `ssh` link instead of the `https` link, I provided in the `npm instal --save http://github.com/...` command